# Human friendly binary encoding

Tags: encoding

Some time ago I came across a website that described a binary-to-text encoding which was human friendly. For example on input (for decoding) it accepted 0, o and O all as the same value, because people tend to mix those characters very easy.

Unfortunately I can't remember how it was called...

Edit: this was the one I was looking for:
"Another [alternative design for Base32 is created by Douglas Crockford](http://www.crockford.com/wrmg/base32.html), who proposes using additional characters for a checksum."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like [Base32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base32).

There are variants (such as [z-base-32](http://zooko.com/repos/z-base-32/base32/DESIGN)) which accept O for 0, l/I for 1, etc.

Comment: The zero '0' character is not part of the Base32 character set.

Comment: Reading the link it seems that the poster wants one of the variations of Base32 rather than the RFC standard version.

Comment: yeah, in the wiki link it mentions z-base-32 which covers 0/O 1/l/I