# What encoding is this binary string?

Tags: text, encoding, binary

I have a binary data file and need to retrieve some data from it.  From trial and error and the help of a hex editor, I have identified the regions of text that I need, but I'm not sure what encoding is being used.

Each character is using two bytes, but in my sample set the second byte is always empty.

```
1F00 : a
1C00 : b
1A00 : d
1B00 : e
1900 : g
1600 : h
1700 : i
1500 : k
1200 : l
1000 : n
1100 : o
0E00 : p
0F00 : q
0C00 : r
0D00 : s
0A00 : t
0B00 : u
0800 : v
0900 : w

5000 : .
5E00 :   <- space

3F00 : A
3C00 : B
3D00 : C
3A00 : D
3B00 : E
2D00 : S
```

for example, the word hello is represented as

```
16 00 1B 00 12 00 12 00 11 00
```

Obviously the weird thing is that 0x41 is not A, and that the alphabet is not even consecutive.  It is possible that some weird cypher was being used, but I doubt it.

**Joop Eggen found the solution below - a simple xor!**

Comment: Seems to be a substitution cipher. Is `1200` always `l`?

Comment: I would guess that it's some sort of ad-hoc encoding, possibly related to a old printer scheme, or the layout of a keyboard.  It's not EBCDIC (related to punched card layout) but there are dozens of others.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/760572/human-friendly-binary-encoding - There are encoding schemes (some RFC-driven, some very obscure) which only use certain letters to avoid confusion. Yours doesn't match anything that I'm familiar with, but you might get some ideas. I was intrigued after reading all the different variations just on Base32.

Comment: Blender - yes, across files these values are consistent (`0x1200` is always `l`).The thing is, my understanding is that these files can support unicode data too - I will see if we can get any sample files demonstrating that too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably saw it already, but one can see the xorring.
This is a poor man's encryption, every char as int:

```
code = (plain ^ 0x7e) << 8
```

Comment: Aha - that's it!  I was just writing out some of them in binary to see if there was anything simple happening.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you on linux try to use enca (it detects character set and encoding of text files and can also convert them to other encodings).

Comment: I'm not on linux, but I thought about something similar and doubted it would work - as I'd just be pulling a chunk out of the middle of a binary file, without any header data etc.  And since the sample data I've got is so simple (all single bytes in double byte encoding) that's not very helpful either.

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely a pattern:

```
    04  05  06  07  08  09  0A  0B  0C  0D  0E  0F  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  1A  1B  1C  1D  1E  1F  
a                                                                                                               x   a
b                                                                                                   x               b
c                                                                                                       x           c
d                                                                                           x                       d
e                                                                                               x                   e
f                                                                                   x                               f
g                                                                                       x                           g
h                                                                           x                                       h
i                                                                               x                                   i
j                                                                   x                                               j
k                                                                       x                                           k
l                                                           x                                                       l
m                                                               x                                                   m
n                                                   x                                                               n
o                                                       x                                                           o
p                                           x                                                                       p
q                                               x                                                                   q
r                                   x                                                                               r
s                                       x                                                                           s
t                           x                                                                                       t
u                               x                                                                                   u
v                   x                                                                                               v
w                       x                                                                                           w
x           x                                                                                                       x
y               x                                                                                                   y
z   x                                                                                                               z
    04  05  06  07  08  09  0A  0B  0C  0D  0E  0F  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  1A  1B  1C  1D  1E  1F
```